# TypeError: expected a character buffer object (trying to write to a text file)

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am trying to code a simple program that writes the output of a function to a text file, and I had it working, but today I tried to run it and it gives me this error at line 54: TypeError: expected a character buffer object.

Here is that line:

```
f.write(spotify.getCurrentTrack())
```

Also, here is the rest of the code:

```
from pytify import Spotify
spotify = Spotify()
import time

var2exit = 1

print "This program was created by Drew Halverson. Do not claim as your own work."
time.sleep(2)
print "This program could not have been created without the help of pytify."
time.sleep(2)
print "Also, this program is not affiliated with Spotify at all and is not an official app."
time.sleep(2)
print "For information on how to use this program and what its use is, check readme.txt"

yes = set(["yes", "y", "YES"])
no = set(["no", "n", "NO"])

r = open("readme.txt", "r")

print "Would you like to read the readme now (type yes or no)?"

choice = raw_input()

if choice in yes: print r.read()
print " "
time.sleep(2)
if choice in no: print "Hi! I will now be checking what song is playing on spotify."
time.sleep(2)
print "Make sure spotify is playing (Only the downloaded application will work. The program is not compatible with the web player version of Spotify."
time.sleep(2)
print " "
time.sleep(1)
print "Have you downloaded Spotify on this computer already? Type yes or no..."

choice2 = raw_input()

if choice2 in yes: print "Alright! Let's go!"
if choice2 in no: var2exit = 2

if var2exit == 2:
    print "Go install Spotify first, then try again."
    time.sleep(5)
    print "Goodbye!"
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.exit()

var = 1

while var == 1 :
    spotify.getCurrentTrack()
    spotify.getCurrentArtist()
    f = open("current_track.txt", "w")
    g = open("current_artist.txt", "w")
    f.write(spotify.getCurrentTrack())
    g.write(spotify.getCurrentArtist())
    print "The current Track is:"
    print spotify.getCurrentTrack()
    print "The current Artist is:"
    print spotify.getCurrentArtist()
    time.sleep(10)
    print" "
    print "Checking again..."
```

I know there are similar questions to this but none that I found exactly answered my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation for getCurrentTrack() -- what type does it return?

Comment: Sorry I am confused on what you mean by documentation.

Comment: Documentation: description, instructions, help file, whatever you have. Without documentation the library source code (or at least the header if there is one) is required to answer your question.